# Google Maps function not defined

Tags: javascript, function, google-maps

I am trying to set up a series of checkboxes so multiple Overlays can be toggled on/off individually in a menu.   I'm just trying to get one layer working before I move on to developing the rest of them.  I am, unfortunately, getting an error when using Dev Tools that states `Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleLayers is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onclick`

I think I have the function defined but keep getting this error.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Removing Overlays</title>
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
    </style>
    <script>


       var map;

        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 5,
            center: {lat: 35.391, lng: -74.447},
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
            disableDefaultUI: true,
          });

        var imageBounds = {
          north: 41.68,
          south: 30.43,
          east: -69.26,
          west: -81.91
        };


            var map = null;
            var layers = [];
            layers[0] = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("https://www.saltwx.com/images/A2020022172000.L2_LAC.S3472.nc.MidAtlantic.chlor_a.png", imageBounds);
                {
              preserveViewport: true};


        function toggleLayers(i) {
              if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
                layers[i].setMap(map);
              } else {
                layers[i].setMap(null);
              }
            }
          }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <input type="checkbox" value="Toggle NOAA Buoy Layer" onclick="toggleLayers(0);">NOAA Buoys</input></a>TURN ON

    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be used as an HTML click function, the routine needs to be in the global scope.  Currently it is local to your `initMap` function.

You will also need the `layers` array in the global scope.

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5mzsa2f6/2/)

[image: screenshot of map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var layers = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 35.391,
      lng: -74.447
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 41.68,
    south: 30.43,
    east: -69.26,
    west: -81.91
  };

  layers[0] = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("https://www.saltwx.com/images/A2020022172000.L2_LAC.S3472.nc.MidAtlantic.chlor_a.png", imageBounds); {
    preserveViewport: true
  };
}

function toggleLayers(i) {
  if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
    layers[i].setMap(map);
  } else {
    layers[i].setMap(null);
  }
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input type="checkbox" value="Toggle NOAA Buoy Layer" onclick="toggleLayers(0);" />NOAA Buoys TURN ON
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

You can leave it inside the `initMap` function if you apply it to the HTML elements using the `google.maps.event.addDomListener` function.:

```
function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 35.391,
      lng: -74.447
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 41.68,
    south: 30.43,
    east: -69.26,
    west: -81.91
  };

  layers[0] = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("https://www.saltwx.com/images/A2020022172000.L2_LAC.S3472.nc.MidAtlantic.chlor_a.png", imageBounds); {
    preserveViewport: true
  };

  function toggleLayers(i) {
    if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
      layers[i].setMap(map);
    } else {
      layers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('toggleBuoyLayer'), 'click', function() {
    toggleLayers(0);
  })
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/5mzsa2f6/7/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var map = null;
var layers = [];

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 5,
    center: {
      lat: 35.391,
      lng: -74.447
    },
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
  });

  var imageBounds = {
    north: 41.68,
    south: 30.43,
    east: -69.26,
    west: -81.91
  };

  layers[0] = new google.maps.GroundOverlay("https://www.saltwx.com/images/A2020022172000.L2_LAC.S3472.nc.MidAtlantic.chlor_a.png", imageBounds); {
    preserveViewport: true
  };

  function toggleLayers(i) {
    if (layers[i].getMap() == null) {
      layers[i].setMap(map);
    } else {
      layers[i].setMap(null);
    }
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('toggleBuoyLayer'), 'click', function() {
    toggleLayers(0);
  })
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="floating-panel">
  <input type="checkbox" id="toggleBuoyLayer" value="Toggle NOAA Buoy Layer" />NOAA Buoys TURN ON
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring toggleLayers function inside the initMap function. That's why you are getting this error. Just declare the function outside the initMap function.

Answer (score 1):

You should load the google maps script before your script.

Because `google.maps.Map` is a function constructor and you instantiate using the `new` keyword, it must be defined before you can use it. And you should also move your script at the bottom or use

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  // your code
})
```